# How to Delete Data Records in database with Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

Can someone tell me what my mistake is when deleting data from the database
Previously, when I used a similar method, everything worked correctly.
But now for some reason when I click to delete the last record, the first one is deleted
I have used several different methods but the result is the same
There is my code in controller

```
public function destroy(Coin $coin)
    {
        Coin::where('id', '=', $coin->id)->first()->delete();
        Coin::find($coin->id)->delete();
        $coin->delete($coin->id);
        $coin->delete();
        Coin::destroy($coin->id);
        return back();
    }
```

There is my route

```
Route::post('/coins/delete/{coin}', 'CoinController@destroy')->name('coins.delete');
```

Comment: what is the error shown?

Comment: Why is this question tagged with Laravel 5 if you are using Laravel 7?

Comment: I have no mistakes
Just removes the wrong line

Answer (score 2):

You are using **[model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#implicit-binding)**, so `$coin` is already a model instance :

```
public function destroy(Coin $coin)
{
    $coin->delete();
    return back();
}
```

Without model binding, you can delete like this way :

```
public function destroy($coin)
{
    $coin = Coin::findOrFail($coin);
    $coin->delete();
    return back();
}
```

Comment: ok im not using this method
worth a try

Comment: Thanks and nice try but still not working((
I dont know what happend im all the time using this method
But at this time he is working incorrect

Comment: Whats not working, can you elaborate more

Comment: I have 5 entries in the db. When I try to delete the last entry, the deletion occurs first

Comment: The deletion is not the one I chose

Comment: Then the problem is on another side. You can dd the `$coin`, some how it will be the last `id`